# Returning ActionResult content in Web API

Tags: .net, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

The POST method below in my controller needs to return custom information in the response:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostStuff(PolicyModel model)
{
      return Ok("Some useful information");
}
```

But on the client, I can't find where this data is:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51812/");
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/stuff", <my json>).Result;
```

'response' just contains the usual header information. I probably don't understand the use of the OkResult. What should I do to return back information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the Client you should look in  response.Content and deserialize the value (i am using newtonsoft json) . Example :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
```

Anyway for returning success status you should just return this from API

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

so the client receives this information in the response and check it

```
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { //do stuf }
```